# How to shorten the length of a PGP message

Tags: string, encryption, compression, qr-code, pgp

I need to generate a QR code from a PGP message. The problem is the code is coming out way too big (about 3 x 3 inches).

How can I shorten the length of the PGP message to generate the QR code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an OpenPGP message depends on:

- The message itself (compressability, length)
- The symmetric encryption algorithm (mainly because the cipher block needs to be stored)
- ASCII armored output is much larger than the binary version, don't armor if it works without
- As @Duncan already said, signing needs further space

Try different symmetric algorithms, and try whether forcing GnuPG *not* to compress actually makes the message smaller (as the compression headers also need a little bit of space).

To look into an OpenPGP message and see what's contained, use `gpg --list-packets`.

Furthermore, you can try to tweak the QR code (redundancy), or put an URL into the QR code which links to the message itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot you can do really. Check your PGP message is using compression, assuming your recipients support it. Otherwise, you have very few options:

- Shorten the contents of your message
- Encrypt to fewer recipients
- Encrypt without signing, if that suits your security model